# Django model from multiple databes tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to ask if there is a convenient way that allows me to create a django model from multiple tables. I am looking for solution, that can be written in similar way:

```
class ClientTeamContacts(models.Model):
    attribute_1 = models.CharField(db_column='ss',db_table = 'xxx')
    attribute_2 = models.CharField(db_column='cc',db_table = 'yyy')
```

I will be thankful for every suggestion that can provide some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without hacking the django core, I think the best you can hope for is something like this:

```
class ClientTeamContacts(models.Model):
    attribute_1 = models.ForeignKey('xxx', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute_2 = models.ForeignKey('yyy', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This will let you access and modify SS and CC despite them living on a different table.

```
record = ClientTeamContacts.objects.get(xxx.ss = 'Smith')
record.xxx.ss = 'Brown'
record.save()
```

Alternatively, look into using abstract base classes, they abstract out common data and may provide a different way to solve your problem:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but this approach can be very difficult to apply if you use lot of tables and serializers, unfortunately we cannot change database structure and we cannot write to the database...we can only do selects and we then create json documents of aggregated data